# mutating react state delete class method

Tags: reactjs, state, mutated

I have a class instance in my react state and it's like below:

```
class Room {
  name;
  participant;
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.participant = {
      screensharing: false,
    };
  }
  sendReinvite() {
    console.log("reinvite");
  }
}
```

after changing screen share and using the spread operator for mutating state, sendReinvite method is deleted and causes an error in the second click:

```
const SpreadOperator = () => {
  const [room, changeRoom] = useState(new Room());

  const toggleScreenSharing = () => {
    console.log("room", room);
    room.participant.screensharing = !room.participant.screensharing;
    room.sendReinvite();
    changeRoom({...room});
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>spread operator</h1>
      <button onClick={toggleScreenSharing}>Screen share</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default SpreadOperator;
```

error:
Uncaught TypeError: room.sendReinvite is not a function
how can I change screen share without losing methods, by the way, that instance comes from some library and I can't change that,

check this like for a real one:

[room](https://github.com/wazo-platform/wazo-js-sdk/blob/master/src/simple/room/Room.js)

Answer (score 1):

#### Do not use spread operator in class instances

Check this link to see [Why can I not use the spread operator on a class function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58058559/why-can-i-not-use-the-spread-operator-on-a-class-function)

Consider the following snippet:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 'a', this.b = 'b'
  }
  mymethod() { 
    return true 
  }
}
```

If you do:

```js
const a = new A();
a.mymethod(); // true
```

And if you use spread operator in it:

```js
const a = new A();
const b = { ...a };
b.mymethod(); // b.mymethod is not a function
b.a; // 'a'
```

#### Do not modify your state directly

Again, [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

You do it in:

```js
room.participant.screensharing = !room.participant.screensharing;
```

So, replace:

```js
room.participant.screensharing = !room.participant.screensharing;
room.sendReinvite();
changeRoom({...room});
```

with:

```js
const myNewRoomState = new Room(); // Create another state object
myNewRoomState.participant.screensharing = !room.participant.screensharing;
myNewRoomState.sendReinvite();
changeRoom(myNewRoomState);
```

This is still doubtful because you are using a mutable class instance to store your immutable state, I recommend you to check this post: [Is there a react way to store a mutable class instance objects in state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062826/is-there-a-react-way-to-store-a-mutable-class-instance-objects-in-state)

But in summary:

- Avoid spread operator in class instances.
- Do not modify your state directly, change it's properties through `changeRoom` function (which is the function responsible for changing your room state).

Comment: but the class comes form a library and cant be guaranteed creating new instance of it be exactly like the one the one that it gives me from an static method of it that i call, so new Room() is out of option :(

Comment: unfortunately I can't tell a solution only by using these infos, may you want to explain better in a new question or update the current one. Try to explain these constraints better (why can't you create a new class instance, even if it's from another library).

Answer (score 0):

Alex did a good job answering this, but I want to add something to help you understand more.

`sendReinvite` exist in `Room.prototype` and doing `{...rom}` won't clone the prototype.