# How to properly cast a value of a base type to its extended type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Given this TypeScript snippet:

```
type URLEx = URL & {
  custom: string;
};

const url = new URL("http://localhost:3000/foo/var");

const url_x: URLEx = {
  ...url,
  custom: "hello",
};

console.log(url);
// {
//   href: 'http://localhost:3000/foo/var',
//   origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
//   protocol: 'http:',
//   username: '',
//   password: '',
//   host: 'localhost:3000',
//   hostname: 'localhost',
//   port: '3000',
//   pathname: '/foo/var',
//   search: '',
//   searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
//   hash: ''
// }

console.log(url_x);
// {
//   custom: 'hello',
//   [Symbol(context)]: URLContext {
//     flags: 400,
//     scheme: 'http:',
//     username: '',
//     password: '',
//     host: 'localhost',
//     port: 3000,
//     path: [ 'foo', 'var' ],
//     query: null,
//     fragment: null
//   },
//   [Symbol(query)]: URLSearchParams {}
// }
```

I was not expecting to see `[Symbol(context)]: URLContext` and `[Symbol(query)]: URLSearchParams`. Why is that so? And how can I convert `url` into `url_x` without manually mapping all properties so logging the latter would produce the following?

```
console.log(url_x);
// {
//   href: 'http://localhost:3000/foo/var',
//   origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
//   protocol: 'http:',
//   username: '',
//   password: '',
//   host: 'localhost:3000',
//   hostname: 'localhost',
//   port: '3000',
//   pathname: '/foo/var',
//   search: '',
//   searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
//   hash: '',
//   custom: 'hello'
// }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't spread the instance of the classes, because classes is a prototype and object spread only [`Shallow-cloning (excluding prototype) ...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals). Instead, you can do this:

```
type URLEx = URL & {
  custom: string;
};

const url = new URL("http://localhost:3000/foo/var");
console.log({...url}); // {}

const url_x: URLEx = Object.assign(url, {custom: 'hello'})

console.log(url.host); // "localhost:3000"
console.log(url_x.host); // "localhost:3000"
console.log(url_x.custom); // "hello"
console.log(url === url_x) // true
```

See [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=35&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgSgGQKIA8oF5aKgMigbwCgooBjAVwGdgB7AWwC4pqAnASwDsBzAbkIF8+hUjQ7Uo5FgBsMUDhADuWBAAoARAAtgwMAwD0eqTVIBDKRprUGAZgAM9vQDMaNPQDcTLNQEo+IsTRSEAB0Rlwq+MFRklL8vlAGBPyEwqLiMQD6KEzwyGiYAPIARgBWEKTAwSaUlGxcHCoxADQEFNT0TADkGhBSRp1xKf6UgSFhjdLBFtTxiWpGpuaWwDb2tmqpAUGhNOGZKFPLs3pQ88Zm0yt29hvDozt70lnBbbR0x6c9fTS3affjMQw6Ew+28CROwBY5AgQA). Beware of [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) since it'll modify the `url` value

Answer (score 1):

Extend the `URL` class:

```js
class URLEx extends URL {
    custom: string
    constructor(url: string) {
        super(url);
        this.custom = 'hello';
    }
}

const urlx = new URLEx(location.href);
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECqBKAZAogD2gU1QFwwOwBMYFFoBvAKGmumAFcJsB7AWwC5pGAnASzwHMqNYEzzc6wZlwAUdLiA7c%20-AJTkhNGhDoAHDDLkgVAbg2bo2ABY8IAOnqNW0ALzQA5JYwgQTN6c0AvhRBFCJi2NCG6K54GADucEho0j7AYNg8oraWXBgAZiYUQA).

See also:

- [Why can I not use the spread operator on a class function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58058559/why-can-i-not-use-the-spread-operator-on-a-class-function)
- [Spread syntax (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

> There are three distinct places that accept the spread syntax:
>
> - Function arguments list `(myFunction(a, ...iterableObj, b))`
> - Array literals `([1, ...iterableObj, '4', 'five', 6])`
> - Object literals `({ ...obj, key: 'value' })`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest composition:

```
type URLEx = {
  url: URL;
  custom: string;
};

const url = new URL("http://localhost:3000/foo/var");

const url_x: URLEx = {
    url,
    custom: "hello"
};

console.log(url);
console.log(url_x);
```

output (depends on URL implementation):

```
[LOG]: URL: "http://localhost:3000/foo/var" 
[LOG]: {
  "url": "http://localhost:3000/foo/var",
  "custom": "hello"
}
```

Comment: This answer changes the nature of the question. With this, I couldn't use the value as an URL type (which would be valid casting). This could still be a solution, but not what was being asked.

Comment: @YanickRochon A almost agree. I am wondering why inheritance is privileged under composition, the provided example was using console.log, which is fine to pass the wrapper.